# XSL Modify Based on Command Line Param

Tags: xml, xslt, ovf

I've got the following XML excerpt. The full XML is the OVF definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" xmlns:cim="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/common" xmlns:ovf="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" xmlns:rasd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_ResourceAllocationSettingData" xmlns:vmw="http://www.vmware.com/schema/ovf" xmlns:vssd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_VirtualSystemSettingData" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" x xml:lang="en-US">
      <Item>
        <rasd:Caption ovf:msgid="network.eth0.caption"/>
        <rasd:Connection>eth0</rasd:Connection>
        <rasd:Description ovf:msgid="network.eth0.description"/>
        <rasd:ElementName>eth0</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>13</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>VmxNet3</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>10</rasd:ResourceType>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <rasd:Caption ovf:msgid="network.eth1.caption"/>
        <rasd:Connection>eth1</rasd:Connection>
        <rasd:Description ovf:msgid="network.eth1.description"/>
        <rasd:ElementName>eth1</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>14</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>VmxNet3</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>10</rasd:ResourceType>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <rasd:Caption ovf:msgid="network.eth2.caption"/>
        <rasd:Connection>eth2</rasd:Connection>
        <rasd:Description ovf:msgid="network.eth2.description"/>
        <rasd:ElementName>eth2</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>15</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>VmxNet3</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>10</rasd:ResourceType>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <rasd:Caption ovf:msgid="network.eth3.caption"/>
        <rasd:Connection>eth3</rasd:Connection>
        <rasd:Description ovf:msgid="network.eth3.description"/>
        <rasd:ElementName>eth3</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>16</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>VmxNet3</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>10</rasd:ResourceType>
      </Item>     
</Envelope>
```

I am trying to insert the line `<rasd:AutomaticAllocation>false</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>`before the `<rasd:Connection>eth*</rasd:Connection>` line but not on all of them. I've gotten the following XSL so far and it works, the issue though is that I have to hard code each interface I want to disable.

```
<xsl:template match="rasd:Connection[text()='eth0']">
    <xsl:if test="$disableEths='true'">
        <xsl:element name="rasd:AutomaticAllocation">false</xsl:element>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="rasd:Connection[text()='eth1']">
    <xsl:if test="$disableEths='true'">
        <xsl:element name="rasd:AutomaticAllocation">false</xsl:element>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="rasd:Connection[text()='eth2']">
    <xsl:if test="$disableEths='true'">
        <xsl:element name="rasd:AutomaticAllocation">false</xsl:element>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there a way to have the user pass in a param containing a delimited list of values they want to disable and if no param is input don't disable any of them? Using xsltproc as the processor if it matters.

Comment: Is it possible the user passes in an XML file of list of values to disable? Then, the XSLT can read in using `document()` function to dynamically add element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, should the user produce an xml file, named for example *DisableItems.xml* like below (which by the way can be produced from text delimited files, .txt, .csv, .tab, etc., using general purpose languages: C#, Java, Perl, PHP, Python, R, VB...):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <disableitem>eth1</disableitem>
  <disableitem>eth2</disableitem>
  <disableitem>eth3</disableitem>  
</root>
```

Then, XSLT can search accordingly using its `document()` function. Be sure other xml file is in same directory as original source xml:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
               xmlns:rasd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_ResourceAllocationSettingData">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="rasd:Connection[text()=document('DisableItems.xml')/root/disableitem]">
    <xsl:element name="rasd:AutomaticAllocation">false</xsl:element>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Output *(notice eth0 not specified in lookup xml does not have the false element)*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" xmlns:cim="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/common" xmlns:ovf="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" xmlns:rasd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_ResourceAllocationSettingData" xmlns:vmw="http://www.vmware.com/schema/ovf" xmlns:vssd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_VirtualSystemSettingData" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xml:lang="en-US">
  <Item>
    <rasd:Caption ovf:msgid="network.eth0.caption"/>
    <rasd:Connection>eth0</rasd:Connection>
    <rasd:Description ovf:msgid="network.eth0.description"/>
    <rasd:ElementName>eth0</rasd:ElementName>
    <rasd:InstanceID>13</rasd:InstanceID>
    <rasd:ResourceSubType>VmxNet3</rasd:ResourceSubType>
    <rasd:ResourceType>10</rasd:ResourceType>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <rasd:Caption ovf:msgid="network.eth1.caption"/>
    <rasd:AutomaticAllocation>false</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
    <rasd:Connection>eth1</rasd:Connection>
    <rasd:Description ovf:msgid="network.eth1.description"/>
    <rasd:ElementName>eth1</rasd:ElementName>
    <rasd:InstanceID>14</rasd:InstanceID>
    <rasd:ResourceSubType>VmxNet3</rasd:ResourceSubType>
    <rasd:ResourceType>10</rasd:ResourceType>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <rasd:Caption ovf:msgid="network.eth2.caption"/>
    <rasd:AutomaticAllocation>false</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
    <rasd:Connection>eth2</rasd:Connection>
    <rasd:Description ovf:msgid="network.eth2.description"/>
    <rasd:ElementName>eth2</rasd:ElementName>
    <rasd:InstanceID>15</rasd:InstanceID>
    <rasd:ResourceSubType>VmxNet3</rasd:ResourceSubType>
    <rasd:ResourceType>10</rasd:ResourceType>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <rasd:Caption ovf:msgid="network.eth3.caption"/>
    <rasd:AutomaticAllocation>false</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
    <rasd:Connection>eth3</rasd:Connection>
    <rasd:Description ovf:msgid="network.eth3.description"/>
    <rasd:ElementName>eth3</rasd:ElementName>
    <rasd:InstanceID>16</rasd:InstanceID>
    <rasd:ResourceSubType>VmxNet3</rasd:ResourceSubType>
    <rasd:ResourceType>10</rasd:ResourceType>
  </Item>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution that I think I will work with. I'll test it out next time I start up my work computer. Will it fail ungracefully if the file is not found or will I need to create an empty file no matter what?

Comment: Should file not be found, depending on XSLT processor an error may appear. Consider keeping a file always even with empty root. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass in a `--stringparam` with a string of a comma separated list of values then with xsltproc you can use the EXSLT `str:tokenize` function as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
  exclude-result-prefixes="str"
  xmlns:rasd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_ResourceAllocationSettingData">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="disableEths" select="'true'"/>
<xsl:param name="con-to-change" select="'eth0,eth1,eth2'"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity"> 
  <xsl:copy> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> 
  </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="rasd:Connection">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=". = str:tokenize($con-to-change, ',') and $disableEths='true'">
        <rasd:AutomaticAllocation>false</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course it would be desirable to use the parameter directly in the match pattern but the use of a variable or parameter reference in a match pattern is not allowed in XSLT 1.0, I thought xsltproc allows it, but in a test having `match="rasd:Connection[. = str:tokenize($con-to-change, ',')]"` I got some error message about an undefined variable, so the above that moves the check into the template is all I can suggest.

Comment: Solution works but I'd like to stay away from extension functions if possible. The reason being is keeping it as lightweight and dependency free as possible.